# C# Display Milliseconds in hh:mm:ss format

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to write a program that has the function to lock the computer after a specified amount of time once the program is activated. The problem im having is getting the time remaining to display properly. I am trying to do this using `datetime` vs a switch/if scenario. display a countdown timer based on a user specified about of time. More specifically what I want to do is

1) the user specifies amount of minutes
2) the minutes is programmatically converted to milliseconds
3 where im stuck) Milliseconds is converted and displayed via label in hh:mm:ss.

I have spent a couple days searching and I don't quite understand the MSDN examples and I haven't been able to come a cross the way to do this. Found plenty of examples for going from datetime to milliseconds though.

Comment: What code do you have so far

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about elementary school arithmetic (unit conversions), not developing software.  First you must figure out how to do it by hand (the formula), then if you need help turning it into code, you can ask here.

Comment: @BenVoigt Dont see how this is not software writing. Was trying to figureout how to display a format programmatically without reinventing the wheel. Doing it long hand (input/60000)-> a(mm) then if a>60 b++(hh), c=60000-a.result(ss) so forth. I wanted to find a shorthand/cleaner way of doing it.

Had no where to start really. I know the community likes to see code attempt but i had no basis to start from that was clear. I was playing with int min = datetime.parse(mm);
datetime end = datetime.parse(datetime.now)
timespan t = min+end
lable.text = t.tostring(hh:mm:ss");

MSDN was just confusing m

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`TimeSpan` would be better suited since you're talking about a *duration*, not a *point in time*.  You can create a `TimeSpan` from milliseconds and then format it with `ToString()`:

```
int ms = 123456;
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(ms);
Console.WriteLine(ts.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"));
```

Comment: Thats so perfect. I swear i tried that and couldn't get it to work. The only thing I can think if is that i missed the @. . Thank you so Very much!

Comment: Glad it worked. `TimeSpan.ToString` is much more fickle than `DateTime.ToString`.